# Fullpage.js android keyboard issues

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have been trying to fix an issue with fullpage. When focus on an input fullpage does not line up he keyboard. The page does not adjust height as you select an input.

works perfect on IOS. fullpage.js adjust then when you click each input the pge moves down a little to show the next input field.

Is there a resolve for this?

http://www.ahimsainvestments.com/#home/register

Only on input fields doesnt happen on golden visa page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Initializing fullpage.js
        initialize(false);
        function initialize(hasScrollBar){
            $('#fullPage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home', 'investment-platform', 'golden-visa', 'ahimsa-investments'],
                controlArrows: true,
                menu: '#menu',
                animateAnchor: false,
                slidesNavigation: false,
                navigation: false,
                fadingEffect: false,
                fadingEffectKey: 'xxx=',
                parallax: 'sections',
                parallaxKey: 'xxx==',
                parallaxOptions: {
                    type: 'reveal',
                    percentage: 50,
                    property: 'translate',
                },
                css3:true,
                easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000)',
                scrollingSpeed: 600,
                autoScrolling: true,
                /*responsiveWidth: 1,*/
                scrollBar: hasScrollBar,
                fitToSection: true,
                fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
                lazyLoading: true,
                scrollOverflow: true, 
                verticalCentered: true,
                afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
                    var loadedSlide = $(this);
                        //second slide of the second section (supposing #secondSlide is the
                        //anchor for the second slide       
                        if(index == 1 && slideAnchor == 'homepage'){
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'left, right');
                        }
                        if(index == 1 && slideAnchor == 'about-us'){
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'left, right');
                        }
                        if(index == 1 && slideAnchor == 'our-team'){
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'left, right');
                        }
                        if(index == 1 && slideAnchor == 'contact-us'){
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'left, right');
                        }
                        if(index == 1 && slideAnchor == 'register'){
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'left, right');
                        }                   }

                });


                //Silentmove links
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('1', 0);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-2', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('1', 1);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-3', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('1', 2);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-4', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('1', 3);
                });     
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-5', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('1', 4);
                });             

                //fadeout bckgrnd on scroll
                // $(window).scroll(function() {
                //  $(".parallax-mirror img").css({
                //  'opacity': 1 - (($(this).scrollTop()) / 250)
                // }); });

}

});
```

Comment: You might avoid many related issues when using scrollbar.  You can rather use the fullpage.js responsive options to turn off autoScrolling on mobile, or try making use of `scrollBar:true`.

Comment: When i do responsive the background image does not cover. you have the image for the screen size and as you scroll beyond that the background is white, i would say that this may be linked again to fade effect and parrallax plugin being used on same site.

Comment: Should no element be "position:absolute" when using vertical align center option